# Thymeleaf: Form submit on click of table row

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a table with orders and order ids. I would like to click on a row to view the order details in another page. My code:

```
        <form id="orderDetalsForm" th:action="@{/restaurant/orderdetails}"
            method="POST" th:object="${order}">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Order Id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Order Details</th>
                        <th scope="col">Date</th>
                        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>


                    <tr id="orderRow" th:each="order : ${orders}"
                        style="cursor: pointer" 
                        th:onclick="'getOrderItems(\''+${order.orderId}+ '\');'">
                        <td scope="row" th:text="${order.orderId}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${order.orderDetais}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${order.orderDate}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${order.amount}"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">Total</td>
                        <td th:text="${grandTotal}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
```

I tried an ajax form submit:

```
    <script>
        function getOrderItems(orderId) {
            var url = "/restaurant/orderdetails";
            $.ajax({
                url : url,
                type : "post",
                data : {
                    "orderId" : orderId
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error : function() {
                    console.log("There was an error");
                }
            });
            
        }
    </script>
```

In my controller I have this:

```
@PostMapping(value="/restaurant/orderdetails")
public ModelAndView orderDetails(@RequestParam String orderId){
    List<Product> orderDetails = userService.getOrderDetails(orderId);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("orderDetails", orderDetails);
   
    modelAndView.setViewName("restaurant/orderdetails");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

While the ajax works, the page is not getting redirected to my orderdetails page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use AJAX to redirect to a page. AJAX is for getting data from the server that is then processed/displayed using JavaScript. You however basically want clicking on the row to behave like clicking a link or (since you are using a POST mapping) submitting a form.

First off, using POST makes this a bit more complicated. You should consider using a GET mapping, not only because it makes this problem easier, but also because a POST mapping isn't really appropriate here. POST is used to send data to the server, which you are not doing.

Another thing you should consider it that using a (pure) JavaScript solution to link the table row hinders accessibility. For example, users that can't/don't use a mouse (such as disabled people or search engines) won't be able to see or even use such a link. To solve this it is a good idea to add a proper link to the row. Then that link can used by "clicking" on it with the JavaScript of the click handler.

```
<tr th:each="order : ${orders}" onclick="orderRowClick(this)">
   <td scope="row"><a th:href="@{/restaurant/orderdetails(orderId=${order.orderId})}" th:text="${order.orderId}"></a></td>
   <td th:text="${order.orderDetais}"></td>
   <td th:text="${order.orderDate}"></td>
   <td th:text="${order.amount}"></td>
</tr>
```

```
<script>
  // Look for a link in the row and click on it
  function orderRowClick(row) {
     row.querySelector("a").click();
  }
</script>
```

Several more points:

- IDs must be unique in HTML. By putting `id="orderRow"` on such a repeated row will result in invalid HTML.
- You shouldn't be using `on...` attributes to assign event handlers. I'm just using it here or otherwise this answer will go too far.
- Remove the `<form>` from around the table. It doesn't do anything.

If you do want to/have to use a POST mapping, then replace the link in the table row with a form with a hidden field containing the order ID and a submit button and in the JavaScript look for the form instead of the link and submit it: `row.querySelector("form").submit();`.

BTW there are several (possibly better) ways to do what you are trying. For example:

- Forget the JavaScript and just put a link into every cell. With the right CSS the row/cells can be changed so that it looks like you are clicking on the row.
- It seems like you are using Bootstrap, which has the ["stretched link" feature](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/stretched-link/). Unfortunately it's a bit tricky to get to work with table rows, but it's worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

What I've understand so far is that you want to redirect user to a new page when the user clicks on the button on the table, for that there're different approaches -

1. **Issue with your approach** - 
   Since you're using ajax it wont be redirecting user to a new page ( because thats exactly how a AJAX works, for more info on AJAX us this link  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX ), unless you explicitly tells your ajax-code to redirect the user on a new page.
   For that you can simply put your page redirection code to a on your ajax success, something like this -

> ```
> <script>
>     //your code
>         $.ajax({
>               // your code
>             success : function(data) {
>                 //page redirection code here
>                 window.location.href = "your-base-URL/restaurant/orderdetails/orderId="+orderId;
>
>             },
>             error : function() {
>                 console.log("There was an error");
>             }
>         });
>      }
> </script>
> ```

PS - This is not efficient programming practice since you're technically making an extra call to your server un-necessarily.

2. Approach 2nd 
   Simply make your html table buttin a-href link , like this -

> ```
> <html>
>   // your code
> <a th:href="@{'/restaurant/orderdetails/orderId=' + ${order.orderId}}">Order details button </a>
>
> //your rest of the code
> </html>
> ```

3. Approach-3rd , You can alternatively use java-script function for page redirection as well, simply modify you ajax function , something like this -

> function getOrderItems(orderId) {
>
> ```
>     //page redirection code here
>   window.location.href = "your-base-URL/restaurant/orderdetails/orderId="+orderId;
> ```
>
> }